# How can I create an alias for apt-get?

Tags: debian, alias, apt-get, apt

I remember that on one Debian system, I used `apt install package` to install a package. It asked for a password afterwards and was more convenient than `sudo apt-get install`.

Now I am not sure how I managed to use the first command. Can you help?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can probably create an alias for that.

Assuming you are using Bash, create a `.bash_aliases` file in your Home directory, if it already doesn't exist.

Then, add a line with the following to the file:

```
alias apt='sudo apt-get'
```

Now close the shell and reopen it again.

Now you can install any new package with the syntax `apt install <package-name>`. Do note that autocompletion will not work with the alias.

Comment: you are right, and since i'am using zsh autocompletion still works, that's great thanks.

Comment: The question mentions Debian which does not use `sudo` by default. In Debian, you have to create alias which use root privilege in /root/.bashrc.

Comment: `apt` appears to be it's own command now (Ubuntu 16.10). For example instead of `apt-get update` you can just to `apt update` now or instead of `apt-cache search` you can just do `apt search`. So making an alias `apt` to `apt-get` might be a bade idea now.

Comment: The `apt` command appeared with Debian Jessie http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html#s-apt-get

Answer (score 2):

It's probably a bad idea to creat an alias `apt` to `apt-get` with recent Debian based distros.  Since Debbian Jessie (2015) and Ubuntu 15.10 (2015) there exists the `apt` command

http://www.debian.org/doc/manuals/debian-faq/ch-pkgtools.en.html#s-apt-get
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/en/man8/apt.8.html

It actually can be used instead of  `apt-get` and `apt-cache`

```
  apt-get update             ->  apt update
  apt-get upgrade            ->  apt upgrade
  apt-get dist-upgrade       ->  apt full-upgrade
  apt-get install package    ->  apt install package
  apt-get remove package     ->  apt remove package
  apt-get autoremove         ->  apt autoremove
  apt-cache search string    ->  apt search string
  apt-cache policy package   ->  apt list -a package
  apt-cache show package     ->  apt show package
  apt-cache showpkg package  ->  apt show -a package
```

It also includes new commans such as `full-upgrade` which is not in `apt-get`.

Comment: That's a good point, but it doesn't answer the original question, it's rather a comment on @jokerdino's answer. By the way, according to the table you've included `full-upgrade` is present in `apt-get`, just named differently.

Comment: @gronostaj, also I think it's useful to give answers which say "don't do that". It was fine to alias `apt-get` to `apt` before 2015 but not anymore. The accepted answer should be updated to reflect this.

Comment: @gronostaj [this answer says](http://askubuntu.com/questions/770135/apt-full-upgrade-versus-apt-get-dist-upgrade) says `dist-upgrade` and `full-upgrade` are the same. This is strange. Why would they create a new name for the same thing.  You can do `apt dist-upgrade` as well as `apt full-upgrade`. It seems stupid to make another name for the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Open up your bash_profile or bashrc. (Probably in ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile). Now add the line `alias apt='sudo apt-get'`. Now save the file, quit your terminal, and reopen it.

Comment: jokerdino beat me to the answer. Using .bash_aliases is probably better than using .bashrc, but jokerdino's answer won't give you the exact syntax you wanted. If you type my line into .bash_aliases (or .bashrc), then you will be able to use the command 'apt install <package>' rather than 'aptinstall <package>'.

Answer (score 0):

"It's probably a bad idea to creat an alias apt to apt-get with recent Debian based distros. Since Debbian Jessie (2015) and Ubuntu 15.10 (2015) there exists the apt command"

Couldn't agree more, I happened to make aliases for 2 of the more frequent apt-get commands (**update** and **upgrade**) as:

alias aptgupd='sudo apt-get update'
alias aptgupg='sudo apt-get upgrade'

Just examples of some other routes, hope this helps.